# How can I prevent seams when attempting to create a skybox for Unity5?

Tags: unity, textures, skybox

After following the [documentation for how to create a skybox](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html), seams are appearing around all sides of my 6 textures (sorry for faintness of image):

[image]

There are no active lights in my scene. **What am I doing wrong and how can I prevent this?** Any skybox creation methodology suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I forgot to set the "wrap mode" for each of the 6 textures to "clamp" rather than repeat. This seems to make all the difference when preventing seams for the skybox material.